# Let $X=U\sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$ and let $X_n = U+\mathbb{I}_{(0,2^{-n})}(U)$. Then does $X_n\stackrel{a.s}{\rightarrow}X$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables. Let $X$ be another random variable. Then, $$X_n\stackrel{a.s}{\rightarrow}X \text{, if } \mathbb{P}[\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n=X]=1$$

That is, $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n>N,$ we have $\mathbb{P}[|X_n-X|\ge\epsilon]=0 \tag{1}$

Let $X=U\sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$ and let $X_n = U+\mathbb{I}_{(0,2^{-n})}(U)$

Then $X_n\stackrel{a.s}{\rightarrow}X$ since, $$\forall\epsilon>0, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}[|X_n-X|>\epsilon]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}[U\in(0,2^{-n})]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}<\infty$$

I am trying to prove that $X_n\stackrel{a.s}{\rightarrow}X$, using $(1)$.

Let $\epsilon\in(0,1)$. Then, $\mathbb{P}[|X_n-X|>\epsilon]=\mathbb{P}[U\in(0,2^{-n})]=2^{-n}\ne 0, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$

And, so for any $\epsilon\in(0,1), \mathbb{P}[|X_n-X|>\epsilon]\ne 0, \forall n\in N$. And so, for these choice of $\epsilon 's$, $(1)$ cannot be satisfied. And so, $X_n$ does not converge almost surely to $X$.  What did i do wrong?

Comment: "And so $X_n$ does not converge almost surely to $X$" This does not follow from the previous work you did

Comment: @Andrew , I have shown that for any $\epsilon\in(0,1), \mathbb{P}[|X_n-X|>\epsilon]\ne 0, \forall n\in N$. And so, for these choice of $\epsilon 's$, $----(1)$ cannot be satisfied. And so, $X_n$ does not converge almost surely to $X$. What is wrong in the above argument?

Comment: Do you agree that $U(\omega)>0$ implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n(\omega)=U(\omega)=X(\omega)$? This while $P(U>0)=1$.

Comment: @drhab, please refer to the edit in my post. Thanks.

Comment: It's wrong because you are misinterpreting the definition of almost sure convergence. It does not say that $P(|X_n-X|\geq \varepsilon) = 0$ if $n$ is large. It says that for each $\omega$, $|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)|< \varepsilon$ if $n = n(\omega,\varepsilon)$ is large.

Comment: $X_n$ converges a.s. to $X$ if $P(\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n=X)=1$. That is the definition of ["converging almost surely"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Almost_sure_convergence). Not what you bring forward as definition.

Comment: i realize my mistake now, thanks.